# How do I input values from a 2-index-level dataframe into a 3-index-level dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an empty dataframe `df1`:

```
              column1 column2
A   B   C
```

I have a 2 dimensional dataframe `df2` with same column, but only B and C as indexes:

```
                  column1 column2
   B     C             
   foo   bar          123     123
   foo2  bar2         456     456
```

How do I efficiently input those values into the 3-dimensional dataframe, with a value of my choice, say 1, for the A column?

The expected output would be (with the same value in all indexes in A:

```
                      column1 column2
 A      B     C             
 1     foo   bar          123     123
 1     foo2  bar2         456     456
```

I tried something like in that format, but couldn't find the right one:

```
df1.loc[('my_value',??,??),:] = df2.values
```

Comment: Chat would be the expected output? If there is nothing in df1 wouldn't it be easier to prepend a level to df2 (`df1 = pd.concat({'A': df2})`)?

Comment: Hi, I just updated my post with the expected output. It would be the same value of my choice for all indexes in A

Comment: You are just looking to add a level to your second df it seems. Also your new multiindex will be (1, foo, bar), (1, foo2, bar2) but you won't see all 1s when you print it.

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to know how to use loc in that case. Also I will be adding many df2's through a for loop, so it would give more flexibility if I just want to add a portion of df2 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this directly and probably should use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df1 = pd.concat({1: df2}, names=['A'])
```

Output `df1`:

```
             column1  column2
A B    C                     
1 foo  bar       123      123
  foo2 bar2      456      456
```

If you have many items to add, use `concat` (**once**) on a dictionary of all items:

```
out = pd.concat({1: df2, 2: df3}, names=['A'])
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I was wondering how can I add TWO columns (A1 and A2)? 
I could execute that line twice in a row, but how can I combine in that one line? something like `names=['A1','A2']`?)

Comment: Of course, but you need to supply 2 keys in the dictionary: `pd.concat({('x', 'y'): df2}, names=['A1', 'A2'])`